# EF: Get list of objects where primary key is not referenced anywhere

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

My current database has a Files table, which is referenced by a couple of other tables.  What I am trying to achieve, is to retrieve a list of Files where the primary key is not referenced at all.

Structure of models is like the below.

```
public class File
{ 
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public ......
}
public class AFiles 
{
    public int AFilesId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("File")]
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public virtual File File { get; set; }
    .....
}
public class BFiles 
{
    public int BFilesId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("File")]
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public virtual File File { get; set; }
    .....
}
```

What I have been trying is:

```
return context.File.Where(x =>
            !context.AFiles.Any(y => y.FileId == x.FileId) &&
            !context.BFiles.Any(y => y.FileId == x.FileId) 
        ).Select(x => x.FileId).ToList();
```

but this throws an error of `Unable to create a constant value of type 'AFile'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.`

Is there an elegant way of handling this, I can't just pull out the full list of FileId references from AFiles and BFiles as this would be too costly.

Comment: Is there a navigation property from the `File` entity to the `AFiles` entity?

Comment: nope. only the reference on `AFiles`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ids = context.AFiles.Select(af => af.FileId)
                 .Union(context.BFiles.Select(bf => bf.FileId))
                 .Distinct();

var files = context.File.Where(f => !ids.Contains(f.FileId)).ToList();
```

Try this

it will result in something like following (SQL Server Profiler)

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[FileId] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    FROM [dbo].[File] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
            [UnionAll1].[FileId] AS [C1]
            FROM  (SELECT 
                [Extent2].[FileId] AS [FileId] 
                FROM [dbo].[FilesA] AS [Extent2]
            UNION ALL
                SELECT 
                [Extent3].[FileId] AS [FileId]
                FROM [dbo].[FilesB] AS [Extent3]) AS [UnionAll1]
        )  AS [Distinct1]
        WHERE [Distinct1].[C1] = [Extent1].[FileId] 
    )
```

Comment: I would prefer to not have to pull out the list of Ids first.

Comment: Sorry, I've now removed ToList() from the first line(did that accidentally). Now ids are IQueryable and result will be retrieved with single database query.

Comment: Ok, this seems to work fine.  Any idea on how scalable this approach would be?  The query it produced didn't look too bad

Comment: Have a look at query execution plan generated in SQL Server. The good thing is that EF produced `Union All` instead of `Union` and there's no `In` statement... try duplicating records in Files table...`Insert into Files (FileId, Name) Select FileId, Name from Files`...later on, what's most important, insert references into FilesA and FilesB and test things. you can test with 1 000 000 records if you execute insert-select multiple times

Answer (score 1):

Here's a query which should do the task you want.

```
List<int> ids;
using (var context = new Context())
{
    ids = (
        from f in context.Files
        from a in context.AFiles
        from b in context.BFiles
        where a.FileId != f.FileId && b.FileId != f.FileId
        select f.FileId).ToList();
}

public class File {
    [Key] public int FileId { get; set; }    
}
public class AFile {
    [Key] public int AFileId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("File")]
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public virtual File File { get; set; }    
}
public class BFile {
    [Key] public int BFileId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("File")]
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public virtual File File { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext {
    public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AFile> AFiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BFile> BFiles { get; set; }
}
```

Generated SQL query

```
SELECT
    [Filter1].[FileId1] AS [FileId]
    FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[FileId] AS [FileId1]
        FROM  [dbo].[Files] AS [Extent1]
        CROSS JOIN [dbo].[AFiles] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent2].[FileId] <> [Extent1].[FileId] ) AS [Filter1]
    CROSS JOIN [dbo].[BFiles] AS [Extent3]
    WHERE [Extent3].[FileId] <> [Filter1].[FileId1]
```

Comment: That still produces the `Unable to create a constant value of type` error for me

Comment: @Thewads I ran this code and it worked for me. Note the class names are AFile and BFile and I added key attributes in the classes. If you drop the DB and recreate the model I think it will work for you

Comment: the key attributes are there in the code, just omitted from question

Comment: Setters on generic elements? Is it surely ok?

Comment: @PeterHorvath just same approach as this guide http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application `{ get; set; }` everywhere